# Disabling Custom Keyboards for Specific Text Fields

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, textfield

I am trying to disable the user from using their own keyboards in one of my text fields. When doing research, I found out that I needed the following code to disable custom keyboards:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: String) -> Bool {
    if extensionPointIdentifier == UIApplicationKeyboardExtensionPointIdentifier {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

However, I would not like to disable the keyboards for all of my text fields. How can I apply this to a certain text field only? Thanks!